# How to kill a process that appeared during bash script

Tags: process, kill

I'm new to bash scripting: I want to kill a process called JumpCloudServiceAccount that appear when running this script https://github.com/TheJumpCloud/support/blob/master/scripts/macos/install_agent_and_serviceaccount.sh

the reason I want to do this is because I dont want the user to see the prompt that occur when the process start and want the script to close this process to keep running then exit

What command I can put that will kill this process if it started

I tried trap on exit but the script anyway wont continue until I manually kill the process

Comment: You could post the question at https://unix.stackexchange.com/ with a shell-script tag.